# How Can I Format a Tumblr Title

Tags: formatting, tumblr

Is there a way to format part of a Tumblr title? For example, I'd like to be able to italicize one word in a title. Anyway to do that?

Comment: Do you mean the page title, or the title used with a text post?

Comment: I mean the title of the text post.

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr reads titles using the {Title} tag, so how it is rendered is determined all at once not word for word. This means that the style of your titles universally depends on the CSS used around them in the hard coding. If you use the traditional manner of titling your posts which is placing the title in the "Title" area, then no this is not possible. An alternative method is to not put a title in that area and instead just post all information into the body.

You would then use the "html" view to code the header as you wish to see it. Default tumblr layouts use h1 /h1 around their headers so this is generally what you would want to use. The reason you are going into html view is because there is no option currently on default tumblr to increase the font size outside of html view.

The very first coding in the html view should be similar to this:

```
<h1>Title with one word in <i>italics</i></h1>
```

Once done, turn off html view, press enter to get off of the title line and continue your post.